# How do I easily access strangely name members of an object?

Tags: php

Simply consider this...

```
<?php

$phoo = json_decode( '{ "a-b": 2 }');

// causes "PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array";
echo $phoo['a-b'];

// causes PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant b - assumed 'b'
echo $phoo->a-b;
```

Aside from using something like get_object_vars() or (array) to convert it, is there any way to access the value at 'a-b'?

Comment: `echo $phoo->{'a-b'};`

Comment: Of course, thank you. Care to put that in an answer?

Comment: [sic] echo $phoo->a-b;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent the `-` being treated as a minus operator, and trying to subtract a constant value named `b` from property `$phoo->a`, you need to do

```
echo $phoo->{'a-b'};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the hyphen, which implies `substraction`.

Try

```
 $photo->{'a-b'}
```